# running DocumentAI ocr job from inside Google Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, ocr, cloud-document-ai

I have tried to batch process pdf document to get ocr with document ai processor inside Cloud Function (type 2).  I got the following error :

```
raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials. The documentai.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default. To learn how to set your quota project, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/adc-troubleshooting/user-creds . [reason: "SERVICE_DISABLED"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "service"
  value: "documentai.googleapis.com"
}
metadata {
  key: "consumer"
```

My quota project is set, I can process ocr just fine from jupyter notebook inside Vertex Ai.

What can be the case and what can be done? Thank you!

I have tried setting quota projects, and it is set. The problem is only inside Cloud Function (second gen)

Answer (score -1):

I've checked for incidents related to this issue but there are none reported inline with the time and date you have raised this.

Please have the time to review [gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/set-quota-project) as it can help you better understand the requirements pertaining to the error message you have received.

> A quota project is a Google Cloud Project that will be used for billing and quota limits. Before running this command, an ADC must already be generated using $ gcloud auth application-default login. The quota project defined in the ADC will be used by the Google client libraries. The existing application default credentials must have the serviceusage.services.use permission on the given project.

You may need to review access permission for the functions you need. Here are some other relevant documents:

- [Function Identity](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#console)
- [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#adc)
- [Set up Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#local-user-cred)
- [Troubleshoot Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#non-default-runtime)

Hope this helps.